# How to temporary save params from edit action in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, e-commerce, checkout

I have checkout page like this:

[image]

Is there any way to temporary save params by rows,(e.g for first Checkout method to save params and  when click continue to show that params(what is entered) below heading, then for Billing Information to save that params and so on)

I know I can acomplish this with js but I'm interested can I do it with Rails

Also I know that is a confuse question but hope you get it:)

Comment: Why do you want to store the params temporary? I would just store them in the checkout objects and enrich that object with each step.

Comment: Essentially I want to show them below each heading until final part(in this case until Payment Information) and when user fill that last part to save it in database